# RingCentral JavaScript SDK (HTTP 400 - Unauthorized for this grant type)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

We have tried to connect to the RingCentral token authentication URL in RingCentral by using the JavaScript SDK.

> https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token

We are getting Http 400(Bad Request) - Unauthorized for this grant type error.

```
400 Bad Request

{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Unauthorized for this grant type",
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorCode": "OAU-251",
            "message": "Unauthorized for this grant type"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var SDK = require('ringcentral');
   var rcsdk = new SDK({ 
       server: SDK.server.sandbox, 
       appKey: 'appkey',
       appSecret: 'appSecret',
       redirectUri: ''
   });
   rcsdk.platform()
   .login({
       username: 'phone number', // phone number in full format
       extension: 101, // leave blank if direct number is used
       password: 'password'
   })
   .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response)
   })
   .catch(function(e) {
       console.log(e.message  || 'Server cannot authorize user');
   });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want your appkey/secret available publicly? I understand it's just testing, but perhaps replacing them with [appkey] and [appSecret] would be a good idea? Same with username/password.

Comment: You mean need appkey within array right ??

Comment: I mean the one in your code - that the world can see here.

Comment: @Aaron sorry not understood

Comment: Your information is visible. I can see it man. If I can see it everyone else can. If I wanted, I could use your secret, id, username, and password that you provided in the post to connect to your endpoint and access your data.

It's not a hard concept. Look in your post, right above this. It's right there. 6 inches above this comment. Your appKey starts with "DVCy" your appsecret starts with "DvE2", your username is a phone number, and your password is a person's name... The entire world can see that. The name "secret" in "appSecret" should clue you in.

Comment: ah its testing account

Comment: I get it, I mentioned that in my first comment, it's just a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JS SDK request is using the OAuth 2.0 password flow grant type. To use this with the RingCentral API you need to ensure your app is configured for this grant type in the OAuth Settings for your app.

See the following Stack Overflow thread for my answer on how to do/verify this, including screenshots.

[RingCentral Auth Token Failed in Curl Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692828/ringcentral-auth-token-failed-in-curl-call/47745436#47745436)